# Actualizar 3 columnas de un registro en base a un listado de 1000 registros

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Espero explicarme.

Tengo un excel con 1000+ registros/renglones que se ve algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacer un update multiple, para cada id, debo actualizar cada valor que esta asignado en columna1, columna2 y columna3.

Hay grupos de renglones que tienen los mismos datos en columna1, 2 y 3.

**Ej.
Cuando el id sea 322, se actualize el valor de la columna1 con 2342987, columna2 con 2342987 y columna3 con 2342987.
Asi consecutivamente con todos los id's.**

De momento solo se hacerlo de id por id.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero la pregunta es sobre Excel o sobre SQL? Ademas no se entiende cuando mencionas que quieres que el id sea tal, asignar 3 columnas, trata de ser mas claro

Comment: Listo, actualize la descripcion. Le agregue un ejemplo. Y si, es SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoro los nombres de los campos en tu tabla, pero solo debes realizar el `update` de la siguiente manera

```
UPDATE <tuTabla> SET columna1 = columna1, columna2 = columna1, columna3 = columna1
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas